# In CakePHP, how to add a controller file to the /app/controllers/ directory, extending this class from a controller in the /core/cake/ directory?

Tags: php, inheritance, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

In `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`, I have this class:

```
<?php
class ImagesController extends AppController
{
    ....................
    function view()
    {
        ....................
    }
    ....................
}
?>
```

The problem is that I needed to modify the behavior of `ImagesController::view()` but in order to do that, I modified `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php` directly. Not a good practice to modify `core\cake\`. I should add code to `app\` instead, overriding classes in CakePHP. What I am planning to do is to revert changes I made to `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`, specifically to the `ImagesController::view()` method. Then, I am planning to add a controller file named `images_controller.php` to the `/app/controllers` directory.  This class would extend the `ImagesController` in `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`, by just adding the new `view()` function, which would override the `view()` function in the core. I think using the same class name in both the `app\` and the `core\cake\` is ok, but I am not sure. I can try that. In `/app/controllers`, all of my classes extend from `AppController`. For example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    ....................
}
```

But now, it seems to me that in `/app/controllers`, I would have to create a class like this:

```
class ImagesController extends ImagesController{
    ....................
}
```

Basically, the `ImagesController` class that I am trying to create in `/app/controllers`, should extend from the `ImagesController` class that I have in `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`, meaning extending/inheriting from this class in `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`:

```
<?php
class ImagesController extends AppController
{
    ....................
    function view()
    {
        ....................
    }
    ....................
}
?>
```

`class ImagesController extends ImagesController` does not look right to me because I am not sure if CakePHP would understand that I am trying to say that the name of my class in `/app/controllers` will be `ImagesController` and that I am trying to extend it from a class called `ImagesController` that is defined in `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php`. How could you achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as an images controller in the CakePHP core, ie whatever you're working on there there already is a modified core.

Comment: @ndm In other words, `class ImagesController extends AppController` should have never been written in `core\cake\libs\controller\images_controller.php` in the first place. All I have to do is moving `class ImagesController extends AppController` from `core/cake/libs/controller/images_controller.php` to `/app/controllers/images_controller.php`, correct?

Comment: Theoretically that should work, yes, but I'm not sure what the person that created the file there had in mind when doing so, and what other things they might have done that maybe will prevent this from working. Ideally the app is properly covered by test cases so you could simply try and see.

Comment: @ndm You were right. It works as you suggested, simply moving the file from `core/cake/...` to `app/...`. Thank you. Please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and have this question marked as having a best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the CakePHP core doesn't ship with an `ImagesController` class, meaning the core has been modified, and the file shouldn't have been placed there in the first place.

As long as this was a simple mistake, and this isn't bound to other modifications that rely on the file being present in the core folder, it should be possible to simply move it into the application level `controllers` folder, ie to `app/controllers/images_controller.php`.

Answer (score 0):

To address the part of your question that involves extending a same-name class, you would do something like this:

```php
namespace App\Controller

use Foreign\Namespace\Controller\SameNameController as DifferentName

class SameNameController extends DifferentName {

//code here

}

[more details here][https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php]
```

Comment: Is that the way to do it in the CakePHP framework or is your proposed solution a general PHP way of extending a same-name class? I know CakePHP is also PHP but it is a framework, so I am wondering if you are following the framework rules or only providing a general way of doing things in PHP without the CakePHP framework.

Comment: It's *the* general PHP solution. I'm not aware of any other method that you could use specifically in CakePHP.

Comment: CakePHP 1.x doesn't support or use namespaces though.

Comment: My suggestion is the general php syntax. And, you'll find that Cake, rather than establishing extra-php methods of working, actually is strongly aligned with php standards and best practices.

Comment: @ndm, `use as` should work whether or not the class in question is in a namespace?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes (in fact, it's not even necessary, you could just reference the fully qualified name, ie `ClassName extends \ClassName`), but you're going to have a hard time using the new namespaced class with CakePHP 1.x.

Comment: Ah yes. I completely overlooked the version. 'No' for on my suggestion.